# ESLint not detecting eslintrc correctly in project root

Tags: javascript, eslint

Whenever I run eslint with `eslint . --print-config` in the project root it detects the .eslintrc file correctly.

However, in subfolders I run it with the same command it is unable to use the correct .eslintrc file.

Comment: This seems more like an [issue](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues) than a question.

Comment: can you post the .eslintrc file here? This is likely due to the `useGlobalEslint` option in your .eslintrc file

Comment: What files is it finding in the subfolders? Have you used the [`"root": true`](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuration-cascading-and-hierarchy) in any of your configs?